# How to add a value to a given key in python 2.7?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of keys->values that I want to add to a dictionary.
Some of the keys appear more than once with different values, so I have to make a dictionary that will contain more than one value per key.
Couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Use [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setdefault` function in `dict`

```
myDict, items = dict(), [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
for key, value in items:
    myDict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print myDict
```

**Output**

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [4]}
```

or you can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict, items = defaultdict(list), [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
for key, value in items:
    myDict[key].append(value)
print myDict
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 2: [4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate if you have the same value multiple times for the same key. 
In any case you want to use a `set()` if you want to associate multiple values with one value to prevent duplicates:

```
org_list = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (1,3)]
result = {}
for k, v in org_list:
    result.setdeault(k, set()).add(v)
```